# Extracting a list of dicts for a Pandas column

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries within a pandas column to designate landing pages for a particular keyword.

```
keyword   | 07-31-2019 | landing_pages                                          |
cloud api |     50     | [{'url' : 'www.example.com', 'date' : '07-31-2019'}, {'url' ... ]|
database  |     14     | [{'url' : 'www.example.com/2', 'date' : '08-30-2019'} ... ]|
```

*There are actually many date columns, but I've only shown 1 for example.

My issue is that I already have columns for each date, so I want to extract the landing pages as a list and have that as a new column.

```
keyword   | 07-31-2019 | landing_pages
cloud api |    50      | www.example.com, www.example.com/other
database  |    14      | www.example.com/2, www.example.com/3
```

So far, I've tried using json_normalize, which gave me a new table of dates and landing pages. I've tried getting the values with list comprehension, but that gave me the wrong result as well. One way I can think of is to use loops to solve the problem, but I'm concerned that's not efficient. How can I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use generator with `join` for extract `url` values (if data are dictionaries):

```
df['landing_pages'] = df['landing_pages'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(y['url'] for y in x))
print (df)
     keyword  07-31-2019      landing_pages
0  cloud api          50    www.example.com
1   database          14  www.example.com/2
```

If not working because strings repr of dictionaries:

```
import ast

df['landing_pages'] = df['landing_pages']
                          .apply(lambda x: ', '.join(y['url'] for y in ast.literal_eval(x)))
```

EDIT: If want maximal `url` by recent dates create `DataFrame` with adding new keys by index values, then convert datetimes from strings and last use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for index of maximum datetimes, select by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for rows with `urls` and last assign column `url` to original DataFrame:

```
L = [dict(x, **{'i':k}) for k, v in df['landing_pages'].items() for x in v]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(L)
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])

df['url by max date'] = df1.loc[df1.groupby('i')['date'].idxmax()].set_index('i')['url']
```

Comment: Thank you, how would you recommend only getting the URL with the most recent date associated with it?

Comment: Thank you again for the revised answer!